# Why am I receiving a "ValueError" message for this program?

Tags: python, matplotlib

---

EDIT (3/12/2017 [9:11 CST]) - So I was able to determine why the number is 235 - 235 is the total number of characters in the strings that were designated to go into the arrays, for the temperature one at least. So now, my problem is finding why it is counting the characters and not the total number of strings.

---

I am writing a program that pulls real-time data from Weather Underground, sorts it into arrays, and then will eventually output a full graphical and textual report.

Presently, I am having trouble getting the data into a format I can use to make graphs with using the module matplotlib. The full code and its module "calculations" are at the bottom of this post.

The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/NWS/weather_data.py", line 254, in <module>
    temperatures_array = np.array(temp).reshape(10, 2)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 235 into shape (10,2)
```

I do not understand why I am receiving this error, as the array should have a size of 20, not 235. If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, and how I might proceed from here, I would greatly appreciate it.

***Important Note :: Do not attempt to run this unless you generate your own Weather Underground API key. It will not work without it. Get a key at https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/***

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from calculations import *
import time as t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("classic")


Juneau = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None, "winddirection": None,
          "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

Denver = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None, "winddirection": None,
          "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

Atlanta = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None, "winddirection": None,
           "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

Honolulu = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None, "winddirection": None,
            "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

Springfield = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None,
               "winddirection": None, "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

OklahomaCity = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None,
                "winddirection": None, "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

Austin = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None, "winddirection": None,
          "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

Montpelier = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None,
              "winddirection": None, "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

Richmond = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None, "winddirection": None,
            "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

Olympia = {"temperature": None, "feelslike": None, "windspeed": None, "windgustspeed": None, "winddirection": None,
           "pressure": None, "humidity": None}

J = Juneau
D = Denver
AT = Atlanta
H = Honolulu
S = Springfield
OC = OklahomaCity
AU = Austin
M = Montpelier
R = Richmond
OL = Olympia

# Data Setting for Juneau
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Alaska", "Juneau")
J["temperature"] = v1
J["feelslike"] = v2
J["windspeed"] = v3
J["windgustspeed"] = v4
J["winddirection"] = v5
J["pressure"] = v6
J["humidity"] = v7
print("\nJuneau Data:", J)

# Data Setting for Denver
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Colorado", "Denver")
D["temperature"] = v1
D["feelslike"] = v2
D["windspeed"] = v3
D["windgustspeed"] = v4
D["winddirection"] = v5
D["pressure"] = v6
D["humidity"] = v7
print("\nDenver Data:", D)

# Data Setting for Atlanta
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Georgia", "Atlanta")
AT["temperature"] = v1
AT["feelslike"] = v2
AT["windspeed"] = v3
AT["windgustspeed"] = v4
AT["winddirection"] = v5
AT["pressure"] = v6
AT["humidity"] = v7
print("\nAtlanta Data:", AT)

# Data Setting for Honolulu
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Hawaii", "Honolulu")
H["temperature"] = v1
H["feelslike"] = v2
H["windspeed"] = v3
H["windgustspeed"] = v4
H["winddirection"] = v5
H["pressure"] = v6
H["humidity"] = v7
print("\nHonolulu Data:", H)

# Data Setting for Springfield
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Illinois", "Springfield")
S["temperature"] = v1
S["feelslike"] = v2
S["windspeed"] = v3
S["windgustspeed"] = v4
S["winddirection"] = v5
S["pressure"] = v6
S["humidity"] = v7
print("\nSpringfield Data:", S)

# Data Setting for Oklahoma City
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Oklahoma", "Oklahoma_City")
OC["temperature"] = v1
OC["feelslike"] = v2
OC["windspeed"] = v3
OC["windgustspeed"] = v4
OC["winddirection"] = v5
OC["pressure"] = v6
OC["humidity"] = v7
print("\nOklahoma City Data:", OC)

# Data Setting for Austin
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Texas", "Austin")
AU["temperature"] = v1
AU["feelslike"] = v2
AU["windspeed"] = v3
AU["windgustspeed"] = v4
AU["winddirection"] = v5
AU["pressure"] = v6
AU["humidity"] = v7
print("\nAustin Data:", AU)

# Data Setting for Montpelier
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Vermont", "Montpelier")
M["temperature"] = v1
M["feelslike"] = v2
M["windspeed"] = v3
M["windgustspeed"] = v4
M["winddirection"] = v5
M["pressure"] = v6
M["humidity"] = v7
print("\nMontpelier Data:", M)

# Data Setting for Richmond
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Virginia", "Richmond")
R["temperature"] = v1
R["feelslike"] = v2
R["windspeed"] = v3
R["windgustspeed"] = v4
R["winddirection"] = v5
R["pressure"] = v6
R["humidity"] = v7
print("\nRichmond Data:", R)

# Data Setting for Olympia
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 = get_data("Washington", "Olympia")
OL["temperature"] = v1
OL["feelslike"] = v2
OL["windspeed"] = v3
OL["windgustspeed"] = v4
OL["winddirection"] = v5
OL["pressure"] = v6
OL["humidity"] = v7
print("\nOlympia Data:", OL)

temperatures = []
temperatures.extend([str(AU["temperature"]) + " F"])
temperatures.extend([str(H["temperature"]) + " F"])
temperatures.extend([str(M["temperature"]) + " F"])
temperatures.extend([str(R["temperature"]) + " F"])
temperatures.extend([str(OL["temperature"]) + " F"])
temperatures.extend([str(J["temperature"]) + " F"])
temperatures.extend([str(AT["temperature"]) + " F"])
temperatures.extend([str(S["temperature"]) + " F"])
temperatures.extend([str(D["temperature"]) + " F"])
temperatures.extend([str(OC["temperature"]) + " F"])

feelslike = []
feelslike.extend([str(AU["feelslike"]) + " F"])
feelslike.extend([str(H["feelslike"]) + " F"])
feelslike.extend([str(M["feelslike"]) + " F"])
feelslike.extend([str(R["feelslike"]) + " F"])
feelslike.extend([str(OL["feelslike"]) + " F"])
feelslike.extend([str(J["feelslike"]) + " F"])
feelslike.extend([str(AT["feelslike"]) + " F"])
feelslike.extend([str(S["feelslike"]) + " F"])
feelslike.extend([str(D["feelslike"]) + " F"])
feelslike.extend([str(OC["feelslike"]) + " F"])

windspeed = []
windspeed.extend([str(AU["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windspeed.extend([str(H["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windspeed.extend([str(M["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windspeed.extend([str(R["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windspeed.extend([str(OL["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windspeed.extend([str(J["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windspeed.extend([str(AT["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windspeed.extend([str(S["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windspeed.extend([str(D["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windspeed.extend([str(OC["windspeed"]) + " MPH"])

windgustspeed = []
windgustspeed.extend([str(AU["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windgustspeed.extend([str(H["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windgustspeed.extend([str(M["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windgustspeed.extend([str(R["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windgustspeed.extend([str(OL["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windgustspeed.extend([str(J["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windgustspeed.extend([str(AT["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windgustspeed.extend([str(S["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windgustspeed.extend([str(D["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])
windgustspeed.extend([str(OC["windgustspeed"]) + " MPH"])

winddirection = []
winddirection.extend([AU["winddirection"]])
winddirection.extend([H["winddirection"]])
winddirection.extend([M["winddirection"]])
winddirection.extend([R["winddirection"]])
winddirection.extend([OL["winddirection"]])
winddirection.extend([J["winddirection"]])
winddirection.extend([AT["winddirection"]])
winddirection.extend([S["winddirection"]])
winddirection.extend([D["winddirection"]])
winddirection.extend([OC["winddirection"]])

pressure = []
pressure.extend([str(AU["pressure"]) + " in"])
pressure.extend([str(H["pressure"]) + " in"])
pressure.extend([str(M["pressure"]) + " in"])
pressure.extend([str(R["pressure"]) + " in"])
pressure.extend([str(OL["pressure"]) + " in"])
pressure.extend([str(J["pressure"]) + " in"])
pressure.extend([str(AT["pressure"]) + " in"])
pressure.extend([str(S["pressure"]) + " in"])
pressure.extend([str(D["pressure"]) + " in"])
pressure.extend([str(OC["pressure"]) + " in"])

humidity = []
humidity.extend([AU["humidity"]])
humidity.extend([H["humidity"]])
humidity.extend([M["humidity"]])
humidity.extend([R["humidity"]])
humidity.extend([OL["humidity"]])
humidity.extend([J["humidity"]])
humidity.extend([AT["humidity"]])
humidity.extend([S["humidity"]])
humidity.extend([D["humidity"]])
humidity.extend([OC["humidity"]])

areas = ["Austin, Texas", "Honolulu, Hawaii", "Montpelier, Vermont", "Richmond, Virginia", "Olympia, Washington", "Juneau, Alaska", "Atlanta, Georgia", "Springfield, Illinois", "Denver, Colorado", "Oklahoma City, Oklahoma"]

temp = []
x = 10
y = 0
while x > 0:
    temp.extend(areas[y])
    temp.extend(temperatures[y])
    y += 1
    x -= 1
temperatures_array = np.array(temp).reshape(10, 2)
print("\nTemperatures:")
print(temperatures_array)

temp = []
x = 10
y = 0
while x > 0:
    temp.extend(areas[y])
    temp.extend(feelslike[y])
    y += 1
    x -= 1
feelslike_array = np.array(temp).reshape(10, 2)
print("\nFeels Like Temperatures:")
print(feelslike_array)

temp = []
x = 10
y = 0
while x > 0:
    temp.extend(areas[y])
    temp.extend(windspeed[y])
    y += 1
    x -= 1
windspeed_array = np.array(temp).reshape(10, 2)
print("\nWind Speeds:")
print(windspeed_array)

temp = []
x = 10
y = 0
while x > 0:
    temp.extend(areas[y])
    temp.extend(windgustspeed[y])
    y += 1
    x -= 1
windgustspeed_array = np.array(temp).reshape(10, 2)
print("\nWind Gust Speeds:")
print(windgustspeed_array)

temp = []
x = 10
y = 0
while x > 0:
    temp.extend(areas[y])
    temp.extend(winddirection[y])
    y += 1
    x -= 1
winddirection_array = np.array(temp).reshape(10, 2)
print("\nWind Directions:")
print(winddirection_array)

temp = []
x = 10
y = 0
while x > 0:
    temp.extend(areas[y])
    temp.extend(pressure[y])
    y += 1
    x -= 1
pressure_array = np.array(temp).reshape(10, 2)
print("\nPressures:")
print(pressure_array)

temp = []
x = 10
y = 0
while x > 0:
    temp.extend(areas[y])
    temp.extend(humidity[y])
    y += 1
    x -= 1
humidity_array = np.array(temp).reshape(10, 2)
print("\nHumidities:")
print(humidity_array)

time = []
time.extend(t.gmtime())
filename = ("Report" + "_" + str(time[0]) + "_" + str(time[1]) + "_" + str(time[2]) + "_" + str(time[3]) + "_" + str(time[4]) + "_" + str(time[5]))

openfile = open(filename, "a")

openfile.write("Temperatures:")
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write(str(temperatures_array))
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write("\nFeels Like Temperatures:")
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write(str(feelslike_array))
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write("\nWind Speeds:")
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write(str(windspeed_array))
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write("\nWind Gust Speeds:")
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write(str(windgustspeed_array))
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write("\nWind Directions:")
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write(str(winddirection_array))
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write("\nPressures:")
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write(str(pressure_array))
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write("\nHumidities:")
openfile.write("\n")
openfile.write(str(humidity_array))

openfile.close()

figure = plt.hist(temperatures_array, color="steelblue")
figure.savefig("temperature_graph.png")

figure = plt.hist(feelslike_array, color="steelblue")
figure.savefig("temperature_graph.png")

figure = plt.hist(windspeed_array, color="steelblue")
figure.savefig("temperature_graph.png")

figure = plt.hist(windgustspeed_array, color="steelblue")
figure.savefig("temperature_graph.png")

figure = plt.hist(pressure_array, color="steelblue")
figure.savefig("temperature_graph.png")

figure = plt.hist(humidity_array, color="steelblue")
figure.savefig("temperature_graph.png")

input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Module "Calculations":

```
import urllib3
import json


def get_data(state, city):
    wukey = [REDACTED FOR SAFETY]
    url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/{}/conditions/forecast/q/{}/{}.json".format(wukey, state, city)
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    response = http.request('GET', url)
    json_string = response.data.decode('utf8')
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
    temp = float(parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'])
    feelslike = float(parsed_json['current_observation']['feelslike_f'])
    windspeed = float(parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_mph'])
    windgust = float(parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_gust_mph'])
    winddir = str(parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_dir'])
    pressure = float(parsed_json['current_observation']['pressure_in'])
    humidity = str(parsed_json['current_observation']['relative_humidity'])

    response.close()
    return temp, feelslike, windspeed, windgust, winddir, pressure, humidity
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems that you're using `extend` in your while loops instead of `append`.

I haven't ran all of your code, but I'm certain your issue is coming from your `while` loops:

```
while x > 0:
    temp.extend(areas[y])
    temp.extend(temperatures[y])
    y += 1
    x -= 1
```

If you print out what temp looks like in each iteration of the while loop, you'll see that `extend` is **splitting each string into a character list** (as `extend` is meant to work -- which is to merge one list into another):

```
['A', 'u', 's', 't', 'i', 'n', ',', ' ', 'T', 'e', 'x', 'a', 's', '1', '2', '3', '4', ' ', 'F']

['A', 'u', 's', 't', 'i', 'n', ',', ' ', 'T', 'e', 'x', 'a', 's', '1', '2', '3', '4', ' ', 'F', 'H', 'o', 'n', 'o', 'l', 'u', 'l', 'u', ',', ' ', 'H', 'a', 'w', 'a', 'i', 'i', '1', '2', '3', '4', ' ', 'F']

... and so on, until you have 235 elements.
```

Your code should be something like this per while loop:

```
while x > 0:
    temp.append(areas[y])
    temp.append(temperatures[y])
    y += 1
    x -= 1
```

Ideone is working again for me. Here's the code snippet I made to see the results: https://ideone.com/zGqxiK

As a small note:

You can make things a bit easier to follow through by using for loops instead of while loops:

```
temp = []
for i in range(len(areas)):
    # append the area, then the temperature
    temp.append(areas[i])
    temp.append(temperatures[i])
```

There are some slight optimizations you can make to your code as well, although I'm not sure if noting them here is deviating too much from the original post (or should be reserved for another StackExchange site or post).

Comment: No problem. Did you want an optimized version of the area/temperature code snippet? Also, if my solution solved your problem, please mark it as an answer. That way, anyone else looking at this problem can easily indicate the solution.